# Kubernetes database migrations during pod start acidity

Tags: kubernetes, database-migration, liquibase

My container is configured to run database migrations (e.g
liquibase /flyway ) upon bootstrap to an RDS instance. My question is:

If two pods attempt to run their migrations at the same time, would this cause an inconsistent state or would acid compliance negate this?

Comment: If possible, I think the best thing is to avoid doing this at all. One possible setup: (a.) do not make the container run database migrations (b.) each time you do a deploy, run a kubernetes Job which runs the migrations (c.) set up initContainers in the rest of your Deployments to wait upon the completion of that Job (hopefully your app is able to detect whether there's a migration that's not yet run)

Comment: Could you elaborate your question? Where is this Database, inside your cluster, outside? You are using Amazon RDS, which type? How many migrations you want to do?

Comment: weichung.shaw thanks for the suggestion. @pjoterS say RDS mysql